# Azure Devops pipeline trigger that just won't fire

Tags: azure, triggers, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 2 repos under the same project in Azure Devops called MyProject and MyProject-Devops. MyProject-Devops contains the YAML files for the Devops (YAML) pipelines. MyProject contains the source code for the applications to be built.
I have a trigger definition like this:-

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyRepoAlias
    endpoint: 'MyEndpoint'
    type: git
    name: MyProject
    trigger:
     branches:
       include:
         - main
```

However a commit to branch "main" in the repository "MyProject" does not trigger the pipeline to run, it used to but stopped working some months back. The pipeline has to be manually run now.
I have seen quite a few similar (but not quite identical) questions raised and from them and the Microsoft documentation the syntax seems file. However I have not been able to restore the operation of the trigger.
Any assistance would be awesome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the repositories are located in the same ADO project why do you use the **endpoint:**? It should work without that.

If removing the endpoint does not help I can only share my bad experience with even the simple triggers in the same repository that stops work after some time.

Usually, the workaround I am applying is to remove the pipeline and recreate it again (it "re-setups" some configuration on the Azure backend) and it starts working again.

There is also a **Trigger issue** option you can check on the pipeline options.
[image]